# Security of ExpressionEngine Safecracker

Tags: security, expressionengine, safecracker

I'm using ExpressionEngine, but I want to make some "content management" templates that are very simple compared to the control panel.

Assume the following:

- Only the admin can register new members.
- Members are trusted people.
- All templates that use safecracker are only available to logged in members.

Does using safecracker in this way weaken the security of the site? Would there be any reason not to do this? Is this the best way to get a very custom look for the "content management"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to any security in EE is the strength of your passwords. If all your members are using strong passwords (and keeping their storage safe!) there is no reason why safecracker should be less secure than the CP.

Aother alternative to simplify your content management for users is to use zoo flexible admin.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-flexible-admin I use it for a lot of sites.

Comment: Thanks. I plan on increasing the security requirements on passwords. I'm glad that can be done through some simple settings.